# Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created using mvvm

Tags: android, mongodb, android-studio, mvvm, realm

working on the realm for the project but I have multiple fragments where I have inserting data and updating same the data. I am using the realm data source class which I got in OFishWild - An open source project developed by MongoDB Team but when I updating the data its throwing the error accessing on an incorrect thread.

Step of update :

Query for getting the current object

```
fun getResidentDetails(id: String): ResidentUser? {
if (id.isBlank()) return null
return realm.where().equalTo("_id", ObjectId(id)).findFirst()
}
```

2. Update the object as per required changes
3. Pass data to ViewModel
4. Pass data to real singleton Class

   fun updateResident(_residentUser: ResidentUser , id: String) {

   ```
     var residentUser =  realm.where<ResidentUser>().equalTo("_id", ObjectId(id)).findFirst()
        realm.executeTransactionAsync({
            residentUser = _residentUser
            realm.insertOrUpdate(residentUser)
        }, {
            Log.d(TAG, "updateResident: Updated item")
        }, {
            Log.d(TAG, "updateResident: ${it.localizedMessage}")
        })

    }
   ```

https://github.com/WildAid/o-fish-android/blob/main/app/src/main/java/org/wildaid/ofish/data/RealmDataSource.kt

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same thread to perform the operation

Ex. if you are on the main thread you have to insert or update data on the main thread same for the background thread

try different methods: copyorUpdate or insertORupdate